# What is the maximum resolution of Recettear: An Item's Shop Tale?

Tags: recettear-an-item-shops-tale

I bought `Recettear: An Item's Shop Tale` on Steam but I can set at maximum resolution of 1280x960. Is it possible set an higher resolution in some way?

Comment: I love Steam's indie pack sales!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the crappy graphics are BY DESIGN. They are using a lot of sprites so zooming more on them won't improve the quality, just the pixel sizes

Comment: I wouldn't say "by design" so much as "sprites are cheaper on an indy-dev's budget"

Comment: It's also worth remembering that the game was originally released in 2007 in Japan. [Compared to now](http://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey/), larger screens weren't [quite as common](http://www.bioware.com/_poll/view_poll.html?pollID=251) back then, so that may also have affected the choice.